# Исключить поддомены из редиректа

Tags: .htaccess

Есть следующий код для .htaccess который делает редирект с http на https. Как сделать редирект только с основного домена, а с поддоменов чтоб также открывалось на http

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```